# Day of the week missing from Nougat 7.0 notification drawer

Tags: 7.0-nougat, calendar

I'm running Android 7.0 Nougat on a Wiko Sunny 2 Plus device. I often need to view the date quickly from the notification drawer. The problem is that I often need it to look for the current day of the week (because people will be giving you appointments in the near or moot so near future by specifying the day of the week and perhaps the number of weeks from this one, and you will immediately want to know how many days are left till that day, as you will need to quickly check your phone to give a quick response) without having to switch to the calendar app (which its more time consuming, as it requires you to unlock your phone with a password first of your phone is password protected, and then switch to the app, plus your phone may not have enough space for the calendar app). My question is, is it possible to configure this top of the notification drawer to also display the day of the week(Monday, Tuesday, etc.), perhaps from the settings? What about in future versions of Android?

Thanks.

Comment: in android oreo 8.0 pull down notification shows like this Fri, 30 Mar(today). Is that the one you required? Search for any update available. Or else use  clock widget on home screen that shows date and day of week.

Comment: can you post screenshot of the current notification drawer and what format you wish to have in it ?